# Sum rows grouped by value in first column - T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

I need query that will do the sum of the colB grouped by colA and then multiply with value from colA. After all summing for different groups all sums should be added in total sum. Number of different values in colA could be any.

```
colA    colB
0.25    100
0.25     80
0.10    200
0.50    160
0.10    500
0.10    150
```

For given example math should be as follows:

```
(100+80)*0.25 + (200+500+150)*0.10 + 160*0.50 = 210
```

Comment: is it not  as simple as `sum(colA*colB)`? grouping doesn;t matter as you only need the final sum.

Comment: I had problems with rounding on each row so finally I had quite gap but anyway I could round after all math.
Basically you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order did matter in this case, you would do something LIKE this:

```
SELECT SUM(Total) AS GrandTotal
FROM (
SELECT  t.ColA, t.ColA * SUM(t.ColB) AS Total
FROM    dbo.Table1 AS t
GROUP BY t.ColA
    ) AS A
```

But this should work in this case:

```
SELECT SUM(ColA * ColB)
FROM dbo.Table1
```